# Hibernate and order by using column values

Tags: java, hibernate

Is there a way I can pull off the below query (order by followed by a like) using hibernate criteria api?

```
select * from table where first_name like 'bar%' order by first_name like 'bar%' desc
```

Comment: Is that valid SQL? What does it do?

Comment: Do not know whether it is part of ANSI SQL standards, but works with MySQL. Say you have a column with values "foo", "foo", "foo", "bar", "bar" and you want your result to be grouped and the grouping to be in a certain order say all "bar"s first and then "foo"s, you can say 'order by column name like "bar" desc, column name like "foo" desc'.

Comment: Weird. That's definitely not standard SQL, and I don't think Hibernate will let you express that, either.

Comment: But isn't this evaluated to true for all matches (or they wouldn't be matches)? So it's basically `order by true`, isn't it? Or is this just a bad example?

Comment: @Abhi - All "foo"s in your example are thrown out by the constraint anyway. `select * from table where first_name like 'bar%' order by first_name desc` should be the same.

Comment: @Thomas no, it's not the same `order by name` sorts by name, while `order by name like 'bar%'` sorts by the boolean result of this expression (which is true for each element in this particular example). Therefore, it's the same as `order by 1` in this example. But I think it's only the example that's bad, `order by [expression]` does have some valid use cases.

Comment: Sorry. The explanation I gave in the comment does not match with the example query I have provided. I have groups of things in database and I want the results to be grouped based on which group they belong to and these groups I want in a pre determined order based on group name.

Comment: Any luck ? I have been facing similar problem and unable to find a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't easily map this query to Criteria API because `Order` class only supports property names / aliases and not expressions.

You can, however, try one of the following:

1. If the underlying database supports the expression you're trying to order by in `SELECT` clause, you can define a [Projection](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html#querycriteria-projection) with some alias (depending on expression you may have to use  `Projections.sqlProjection()` to do so) and then order by that alias.
2. Otherwise, you can extend `Order` class and overwrite its `toSqlString()` method to generate SQL as you see fit. Be careful that you don't make it non-portable across different databases.

P.S. To address some of the above comments, I'm pretty sure that `ORDER BY expression` is ANSI SQL standard (can't be 100% sure, though, seeing as how it's not publicly available). It's certainly a de-facto standard - it's supported by latest MySQL / PostgreSQL / Oracle / SQL Server versions.

Comment: I do not want to extend Order class. If I go the projection way, will not the sql in projection be part of the select query?

Comment: Certainly will. That's why I said you can only do that if your database supports such an expression as part of `SELECT` clause. If that's not the case and you don't want to extend `Order` (why?) your only option is to use native SQL query instead of `Criteria`.

Comment: I was using SQL query but thought it will become more comprehensible if I do it using criteria API. But, extending Order will confuse people more than help. Also, this is only for a small task which is sort of one off. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your just looking for `order by first_name desc`...

Answer (score 0):

this can be done using the addOrder method of the criteria API:

```
List<Customer> result=(List<Customer>) session.createCriteria(Customer.class)
                           .add(Restrictions.like("firstName", "bar%"))
                           .addOrder(Order.desc("firstName"))
                           .list();
```

check here:

[Hibernate Criteria Api](https://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/v3/api/org/hibernate/Criteria.html)

Comment: Thanks. But this does not take the like criteria while ordering.

Answer (score 0):

You can do following trick:

```
cachedCriteria.add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction("1=1 order by " + your_expression_here);
```

The sqlRestriction works as following - it adds AND to the end of query and insert your expression.